# Excel 2013 Macros/ sub procedures

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2013

After creating sub procedures, they are not considered part of the macro group. Why? How should a sub procedure be created so it is included in the list of macros?

Comment: If my answer doesn't help as-is, please edit your question to include an example of the subroutine(s) you're having problems with, and explain exactly how and where you created it within Excel. If you include pubic links to screenshots (ie: host them on imgur.com), that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

The default place for macro subroutines is in a Module added to the VBA Project for the Book.

[image: VBA Solution Explorer]

*But* they should also be listed if you add them to Sheet or the ThisWorkbook objects.

I created a sub routine in each, plus one in a module I added, and here's the Macro list:

[image: Excel Macro List]

All three of these sub routines have the same test syntax and content, e.g.:

```
Sub TestingSheet()
  'Nothing
End Sub
```

If yours are not appearing as above, I'd first double-check to ensure your subroutine syntax is correct.